# Colorful print ad in ca. 1990 magazine

Tags: software

I'm trying to find a software ad in a comic book style that I remember from one of my father's computer magazines in the early 1990s. I know this is a long shot, but somebody might recall it or even still have a magazine with that ad.

The details I remember:

- The ad was full page, landscape. It contained a single scene and was drawn in a colorful comic book style, in technique similar to Tintin.

  [image]
  It featured two humans on a busy platform, overlooking a futuristic city. The platform was full of funky aliens (think Mos Eisley cantina clientele, but friendly).
- The two humans had a speech balloon each. One was full of technobabble (for me at that time a least; it must have been a list of software features), the other bubble contained just the name of the product. I can't shake the feeling it was [Clipper 5.01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(programming_language)), but I'm pretty certain it was in the form "product_name version_number".
- I'm pretty certain it was a German magazine, because that's what we had access to. The ad was on the back cover. I browsed through the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/computermagazines) to at least find the name of the magazine. The only one that I found familiar there is [c't](https://archive.org/details/ct-magazine), but there are only issues from the mid 1980s. I'm hoping the ad was running in other magazines as well.
- I would place the timeframe in the early 1990s. If the ad was in fact for Clipper 5.01, which was released in April 1991, the magazine would be from from around that time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Funny, I do remember this ad.

Just found some images from the clipper 5.0 advertising campaign on
[brand-history.com/nantucket-gmbh/nantucket](http://brand-history.com/nantucket-gmbh/nantucket)

The second last one seems to be it.

[image: screenshot]

It has been designed for Nantucket Germany back in 1992...

...and does indeed have that comic book style you mentioned!

---

Google Translate gives:

> Saint Newton! When I see this galactic chaos here, I think of tons of
>   tasks. For which I absolutely need a super-capable development system!
>   No memory limit at 640 K. and I want to be able to extend the
>   linguistic scope by UDF's and UDC's. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: That's it, thank you @Uli! It seems I mixed the memory of the city vista from somewhere else. Idea for new question: What are the inspirations for some of the characters? The kissing couple on the left reminds me of the WW2 V-J Day Kiss photo. The guy in the oversized orange pants in the center and the horned creature on the right I also find familiar.

Comment: For the record, Google Translate gives: _Saint Newton! When I see this galactic chaos here, I think of tons of tasks. For which I absolutely need a super-capable development system! No memory limit at 640 K. and I want to be able to extend the linguistic scope by UDF's and UDC's. Can you give me a tip?_